# pandas create new columns with str.split on '\'

Tags: python, pandas

What is the more elegant way to create news cols for each part of a path string ?

With this data:

```
>>> data = {'table': 
 {0: '/1BCDWB/IQ0001',
  1: '/1BEA/BBEA_BDH',
  2: '/2BA',
  3: '/4R',}}
>>> ddf = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> ddf
            table
0  /1BCDWB/IQ0001
1  /1BEA/BBEA_BDH
2            /2BA
3             /4R
>>>
```

I need to add a `t1` column with ['IQ0001', 'BBEA_BDH', '2BA', '4R'] and `t2` with ['1BCDWB', '1BEA', '', '']

for now the best I found is:

```
>>> ddf['t1'] = ddf.table.str.rsplit('/', 2).str.slice(-1, -2, -1)
>>> ddf
            table          t1
0  /1BCDWB/IQ0001    [IQ0001]
1  /1BEA/BBEA_BDH  [BBEA_BDH]
2            /2BA       [2BA]
3             /4R        [4R]

>>> ddf['t2'] = ddf.table.str.rsplit('/', 2).str.slice(-2, -3, -1)
>>> ddf
            table          t1        t2
0  /1BCDWB/IQ0001    [IQ0001]  [1BCDWB]
1  /1BEA/BBEA_BDH  [BBEA_BDH]    [1BEA]
2            /2BA       [2BA]        []
3             /4R        [4R]        []
```

but I don't understand why values are in a list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `extractall` and `unstack`:

```
out = ddf.join(ddf['table']
 .str.extractall('([^/]+)')[0].unstack()
 .rename(columns=lambda x: f't{x+1}')
)
```

or `split` with `expand=True`:

```
out = ddf.join(ddf['table']
 .str.rsplit('/', expand=True).iloc[:, 1:]
 .add_prefix('t')
)
```

output:

```
            table      t1        t2
0  /1BCDWB/IQ0001  1BCDWB    IQ000
1  /1BEA/BBEA_BDH    1BEA  BBEA_BDH
2            /2BA     2BA       NaN
3             /4R      4R       NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ddf.assign(t1=ddf.table.str.split('/').map(lambda x:x[-1]))\
    .assign(t2=ddf.table.str.split('/').map(lambda x:x[-2])).pipe(print)
```

out

```
            table        t1      t2
0  /1BCDWB/IQ0001    IQ0001  1BCDWB
1  /1BEA/BBEA_BDH  BBEA_BDH    1BEA
2            /2BA       2BA        
3             /4R        4R
```